# Emacs - using Chrome as default browser when clicking links

Tags: google-chrome, emacs

Every time I click a link in emacs, it opens Firefox (I'm running Ubuntu).  I'd like to replace that with Chrome.

I've tried

`(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic
browse-url-generic-program "google-chrome")`

as per http://evan-tech.livejournal.com/268748.html but it does not work for me.

Emacs version: GNU Emacs 23.1.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.20.1) of 2011-03-04 on allspice, modified by Debian

Comment: That solution works for me, did you put `(setq ...)` to your `~/.emacs`?

Comment: Could you please include your emacs version?

Comment: @cYrus yes I did put it in my .emacs

Answer (score 2):

might try the solution here
[Link](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/elisp_browse_url.html)

summary: write a command that makes a shell call to launch chrome executable with a url.

Answer (score 0):

If Chrome is configured as your default desktop browser you may be able to launch it using xdg-open by putting

`(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic browse-url-generic-program "gnome-open")`

in your .emacs.